# Bad argument `127.0.0.1' in iptables

Tags: logs, iptables

```
-A OUTPUT --destination ! '127.0.0.1' -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "new_connection " --log-level 7
```

gives me

```
Bad argument `127.0.0.1'
```

What am I doing wrong? I used this docs : http://www.iptables.info/en/iptables-matches.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The docs are out of date/misleading.

The `!` should go before `--destination`, not after it.  Try:

```
-A OUTPUT ! --destination 127.0.0.1 -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "new_connection " --log-level 7
```

The clue is the summary line in the [man page](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html#lbAI):

```
    [!] -d, --destination address[/mask][,...]
```